# WebfontLoader inactive Internet Explorer Custom fonts

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-11, google-webfonts

I've done a lot of research into Google's WebfontLoader and I'm running into a very nuanced issue when loading a custom font. I'm trying to use the events (active/inactive) of WebfontLoader to detect whether font downloads have been disabled. It seems to work on IE with Google Fonts (like Tangerine), it shows active when Font Download is enabled and inactive when Font Download is disabled. However, when I try to load a custom font, I get good results in Chrome and Firefox (can correctly identify if the font loaded) but Internet Explorer 11 says inactive for the custom font (failed to load) regardless of whether font download is enabled or not (says it failed even when the iconfont loads).

Does anyone know why IE 11 would always return inactive for iconfonts? I do not believe changing my testStrings will resolve the issue (as I have seen others have done in other posts).

Comment: what else does it say? e.g. the web console, network, caniuse.com, etc. IE11 is *nowhere near as modern* as EDGE, it's really behind and will never be updated in certain respects, so IE11 not working on a modern WebAPI is not too surprisinging. What is support for it?

Comment: Edge has the same problem: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/issues/349